# Recursively iterate through nested object to deep copy AND apply defaults from separate data source

Tags: javascript, object

Ok, this one might be a doozy. I'm banging away but wonder if there's an elegant way to approach this.

I have an object of assets, each of which has some properties, as well as some number of sub-assets in either of two possible objects: assets and characteristics.

I also have a flat object with the defaults for each type of asset stored.

I would like to iterate through the object, detect the type of asset I'm looking at from the ID, load the properties from the flat defaults object, overwrite any of those that's present in the nested object, and return a new nested object that's got all the defaults, but is also updated with anything present in the original nested object.

For example, the nested object:

```
{
  "id": "Bohemian Rhapsody",
  "version": "0.10.1.5",
  "manifest": "6s43qhuy53as980u08647ugp864q867-08d4svbn9uh54xc8vu",
  "slug": "DarkShiftingBolt",
  "visibility": "friends",
  "locked": true,
  "values": {"value0":2},
  "assets": [
    {
      "id": "I see",
      "assets": [
        {
          "id": "a little",
          "name": "Queen",
          "values": {
            "value1": 1,
            "value2": 3,
            "value3": 2
          },
          "characteristics": [
            {
              "id": "silhouetto",
              "assets": [
                {
                  "id": "of a man",
                  "values": {
                    "value4": 3,
                    "value5": 1
                  },
                  "assets": [
                    {"id": "Scaramouche"}
                  ]
                }
              ]
            }
          ],
          "assets": [
            {"id": "Scaramouche"}
          ]
        },
        {
          "id": "will you",
          "name": "Freddy",
          "values": {
            "value1": 1,
            "value2": 0,
            "value3": 3
          },
          "assets": [
            {
              "id": "do the",
              "assets": [
                {"id": "fandango"}
              ]
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

The flat defaults object:

```
{
  "Bohemian Rhapsody": {
    "visibility": "hidden",
    "locked": false,
    "values": {"value0":1},
  },
  "I see": {
    "cost": 4
  },
  "a little": {
    "values": {
      "value2": 1,
      "value4": 5
    },
  },
  "silhouetto": {
    "cost": 1
  },
  "of a man": {
    "genre": "opera"
  },
  "Scaramouche": {
    "rank": 3
  },
  "will you": {
    "values": {
      "value4": 0
    },
  },
  "do the": {
    "signature": [[4,4],[2,4],[6,8]]
  },
  "fandango": {
    "records": ["thunderbolts","lightning"]
  }

}
```

The desired output object:

```
{
  "id": "Bohemian Rhapsody",
  "version": "0.10.1.5",
  "manifest": "6s43qhuy53as980u08647ugp864q867-08d4svbn9uh54xc8vu",
  "slug": "DarkShiftingBolt",
  "visibility": "hidden",
  "locked": false,
  "values": {"value0":1},
  "assets": [
    {
      "id": "I see",
      "cost": 4,
      "assets": [
        {
          "id": "a little",
          "name": "Queen",
          "values": {
            "value1": 1,
            "value2": 1,
            "value3": 2,
            "value4": 5
          },
          "characteristics": [
            {
              "id": "silhouetto",
              "assets": [
                {
                  "id": "of a man",
                  "genre": "opera",
                  "values": {
                    "value4": 3,
                    "value5": 1
                  },
                  "assets": [
                    {
                      "id": "Scaramouche",
                      "rank": 3
                    }
                  ]
                }
              ]
            }
          ],
          "assets": [
            {
              "id": "Scaramouche",
              "rank": 3
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "id": "will you",
          "name": "Freddy",
          "values": {
            "value1": 1,
            "value2": 0,
            "value3": 3,
            "value4": 0
          },
          "assets": [
            {
              "id": "do the",
              "signature": [[4,4],[2,4],[6,8]],
              "assets": [
                {
                  "id": "fandango",
                  "records": ["thunderbolts","lightning"]
                }
              ]
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

What I'm trying is an object.keys recursive function that builds a new object from the properties it finds. I'm curious to know if there's a smarter way to go about it.

Comment: If you don't want to roll your own you could use an off-the-shelf solution like [deepmerge](https://www.npmjs.com/package/deepmerge).

Comment: @rayhatfield Thanks, that works for almost all cases (along with some iterative junk)

Answer (score 1):

Got it thanks to @rayhatfield.

```
import * as merge from 'deepmerge';

    this.manifest = (manifestData  as  any).default;
    this.list = (listData  as  any).default;
    this.list = this.assetIterate(this.list);

  assetIterate(asset){
    let id = asset.id;
    let type = this.manifest.asset_catalog[id].type;
    let newAsset = merge.all([this.manifest.asset_taxonomy[type],this.manifest.asset_catalog[id],asset])
    Object.keys(asset).forEach((key) => {
      if(key === "characteristics" || key === "assets"){
        newAsset[key] = [...asset[key]] 
        newAsset[key].forEach((asset,index) => {
          newAsset[key][index] = this.assetIterate(asset);
        });
      }
    });
    asset = {...newAsset}
    return asset
  }
```

Seems to work for all cases except a corner case in which a sub array needs to have indices replaced instead of concatenated, but I can special-case that when I actually make one of those.